# How to append to array in Amazon States Language?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Say I have a state whose input is

```json
{'myList': ['foo', 'bar']}
```

and whose result is `hello`, and I want to append the result to the list so that the state's output becomes

```json
{'myList': ['foo', 'bar', 'hello']}
```

I would actually like to do this for several consecutive states, so that each one appends its result to a list stored in the input object.

Is there a way to do this? From reading [Input and Output Processing](https://states-language.net/#filters) and [Intrinsics for arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays), I'm not seeing a solution.

Comment: Not sure if this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194679/combining-aws-step-function-task-and-map-outputs-in-to-one-array

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-shot option using only [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) that appends the new element `hello` (assumed to be at `$.appendMe`) to `$.myList`:

```json
"States.StringToJson(States.Format('[{},\"{}\"]', States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit(States.JsonToString($.myList), '[]'),0), $.appendMe))"
```

What's happening?  Read from the inside out:

1. `JsonToString` stringifies the array: `"[\"foo\", \"bar\"]"` (string)
2. `StringSplit` splits the array using square brackets as delimeters: `[ "\"foo\", \"bar\"" ]` (array with one string element)
3. `ArrayGetItem` extracts the only element:  `"\"foo\", \"bar\"` (string)
4. `Format` adds the new item and brackets to the string: `"[\"foo\", \"bar\", \"hello\"]"` (string)
5. `StringToJson` parses it to a JSON array:  `["foo", "bar", "hello"]` (array)