# Combining JsonPath listAt and stringAt to make a single array in AWS Steps/CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, json-path-expression

I am invoking an AWS Steps orchestration - and one of the contained steps is to invoke an ECS Fargate Task.

I currently pass some of the Steps' inputs as the "command" of the ECS Task using `JsonPath.listAt`. I would like to also add a single extra value to the command array - but I cannot work out the syntax as a construct within CDK.

Our step's input is:

```json
{
  "indexes": [
    "s3://bucket/test1.bam",
    "s3://bucket/test2.bam"
  ],
  "reference": "hg38"
}
```

And the example of us passing the indexes as command arguments to the ECS Task is:

```js
new EcsRunTask(this, "Job", {
      integrationPattern: IntegrationPattern.RUN_JOB,
      cluster: fargateCluster,
      taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
      containerOverrides: [
        {
          command: JsonPath.listAt("$.indexes"),
```

I want to also pass `JsonPath.stringAt("$.reference")` in as the first argument of the command but I cannot get the syntax correct.

`JsonPath.listAt` is the only JsonPath function that returns a string[] (needed by `.command` in typescript CDK).

`JsonPath.array` can be used to build arrays - but cannot take in inputs in the same way as `listAt` (as in it won't flatten out an existing array input).

---

```js
command: [
  JsonPath.stringAt("$.reference"),
  ...JsonPath.listAt("$.indexes"),
]
```

fails with

`Cannot use JsonPath fields in an array, they must be used in objects`

---

```js
command: JsonPath.array(
            JsonPath.stringAt("$.reference"),
            ...JsonPath.listAt("$.indexes")
          ) as any
```

fails with

`Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Found an encoded list token string in a scalar string context. Use 'Fn.select(0, list)' (not 'list[0]') to extract elements from token lists..`

Comment: So you want to prepend `hg38` to the `indexes` array?

Comment: Yes - so that the command invoke ends up as [
    "hg38", "s3://bucket/test1.bam", "s3://bucket/test2.bam"
]

Comment: Got it.  Will the `indexes` array in the input always have 2 elements?

Comment: No, indexes needs to support variable lengths of input array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least bad option is a two step process: merge then flatten.

First, add a Pass State to merge the inputs.  The state will output a nested array: `[["hg38"], ["s3://bucket/test1.bam", "s3://bucket/test2.bam"]]`:

```js
const merge = new sfn.Pass(this, "merge", {
  parameters: {
    merge: sfn.JsonPath.array(
      sfn.JsonPath.array(sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.reference")),
      sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.indexes"), // CDK does not accept listAt here; the array param is of type []string
    ),
  },
  resultPath: "$.merge",
});
```

Now your command can use JSONPath [wildcard syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73624240/1103511) to flatten the array into the desired shape of `["hg38", "s3://bucket/test1.bam", "s3://bucket/test2.bam"]`:

```js
command: sfn.JsonPath.listAt("$.merge.merge[*][*]")
```

Note that this roundabout approach is needed because of how Step Functions' [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) work.  It's not a limitation imposed by the CDK.

Comment: Wish there was an easier way to do with Intrinsic functions - but as you say - I think this is the least bad option. Thanks (have tried this code and is working well)

Comment: @AndrewPatterson Glad to help.  Perhaps AWS will add a native intrinsic `push` function one day.  In the meanwhile, there is a ludicrously complex [nested intrinsic function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588416/how-to-append-to-array-in-amazon-states-language/77448947#77448947) that will append to an array in a single step.  I didn't mention that alternative, though, because the CDK return type wouldn't match what your `command` param expects.